# Android Keychain for storing RSA keys of size 8192

Tags: android, encryption, rsa, key-pair

I want to store RSA key pairs of size 8192 securely within the android device. Is it possible to use android keychain ? Is there any other way to store the keys securely?

Android key store cannot be used for storing keys of size 8192

Comment: You can encrypt them using e.g. AES or a smaller RSA key & AES. That would have negative security consequences of course as the smaller RSA keys would be easier to break and the protected key would end up in unprotected memory (etc.). That would however be of little use to an attacker that doesn't have enough access to your device; they would still have to crack the higher bit sized key.